# how to use force:navigateToURL in lightning components to navigate from one lightning component to another in communities?

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning-community, forcenavigatetourl

In communities, navigateToComponent or Lightning:navigation are not supported. So i found over the web force:navigateToURL is the way to go with. I am not able to make this work. I think the URL that i am trying to build is wrong. Can anyone suggest me the right way of using force:navigateToURL to navigate from one lightning component to another in communities?

I tried something like this. It did not work.

```
gotoAnotherComponent : function (component, event, helper) {  
    var urlEvent = $A.get("e.force:navigateToURL");  
    urlEvent.setParams({  
      "url": "/cmp/c__componentName"  
    });  
    urlEvent.fire();  
}
```

Comment: you cant navigate in between components with force:navigateToURL (as the component name suggests) - can you please update your post with further details, such as what and how you are trying?

Comment: This is not a duplicate. Over there also the solution for navigation is not provided.

Comment: where is your second component present? On a community page?

Answer (score 1):

You can't use the event to navigate in between components (as the name of the event suggests itself - `navigateToURL`)

If you are navigating to Another page, use it as it is intended to:

```
gotoURL : function (component, event, helper) {
var urlEvent = $A.get("e.force:navigateToURL");
urlEvent.setParams({
  "url": "this is the relative path in your community - NOT a Component"
});
urlEvent.fire();
}
```

If you need to "switch" from one componet to another, you will actually have to manage the rendering and use lighting Events to do so (there is no magic here). There are many ways of doing so,

You can also use [aura:renderIf](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/aura:renderIf/documentation) for example, or, use a tab component, embed different components in it and change tabs based on x. There are many ways of ahcieving this...

Comment: I want to use community pages. Do you know how can i pass parameters to a lightning component embedded into a community page?  
And then i will navigate to that community page using navigatetoURL.

Comment: like, a record id? or some srando string?

Comment: Yea like just a String. Record id can be passed directly(hasrecordId interface). but for string we need design attribute. I am not able to make the design attribute work. So the thing is in url i am appending this string with a url parameter like                                
?recordId=something&var1=somestring. But i am not getting the value of var1 in the design attribute. Also i dont want to do cheap tricks like parsing the URL in init method cause thats easy. I want a specific design attribute related solution.

Comment: create a component that will store those values, or use localstorage?

Comment: there are sections in the community that are persistent, such as the header, or footer. you can use a component to store attributes and then fetch from other components on other pages

Answer (score 1):

lightning-navigation is now supported in Communities as of Spring '19!
https://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/spring19/release-notes/rn_networks_navigationchanges.htm

There are some restrictions though :(. Currently I don't think state is supported, which would fit your exact use case for passing parameters to another page/component. However, we are working on supporting it and should be out soon!

For now though, there are a number of ways as the community laid out:

1. sessionStorage or localStorage. I'd recommend sessionStorage in your case, so that the storage does not last past the page session: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/sessionStorage
   For this you store some unique id that the component you are navigating to can pull from.
2. Create a component to store the info and put in the theme section (header or something) that is persistent throughout the community.

But ideally once we support state in lightning-navigation, which should be out soon, you can then pretty easily navigate to a component and have custom params passed to it.
This video starting around the 7 min mark, explains the use case I was talking about: https://www.salesforce.com/video/2646474/

Keep your eyes out on the Summer '19 release!